# Terraria LAN connection issue

Tags: technical-issues, terraria

So me and my Sister were playing Terraria (1.4.1.1)via the LAN connection just fine, Until it randomly stopped working and now whenever we try to connect to each other's worlds we get stuck on the forever connecting screen..

We made sure that Terraria was allowed through the Firewall, We ran a couple of Virus scans and we
tried reinstalling it but it was all to no avail..

I'm hoping that we can find an answer to this annoying problem and return to our Terrarian world.

Comment: Do you have this issue using LAN features on other games or things?

Comment: Open the terminal (cmd or powershell on Windows, Terminal on Linux or macOS) and try `ping [server ip]` and replace `[server ip]` with the ip of your Terraria server. Does the server respond? If no, the server may have received a new IP address from your router.

Comment: @Penguin I tried using LAN in Minecraft and the server showed up but i couldn't connect to it (stuck on "connecting to" just like Terraria)

Comment: @Nolonar The command prompt showed the following "E:\User\Acer>ping192.168.1.109

Pinging 192.168.1.109 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.109:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),"

Comment: This is actually the first time I see a response to a ping come from a different IP address... However, "*Destination host unreachable*" means the server's IP is no longer correct. I guess the next sensible thing to do is to open the terminal on the server and try `ipconfig` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux/macOS). You'll get a list of different network interfaces and their IP addresses. One of these addresses should be in the form of `192.168.1.xyz` where `xyz` is a 1-3 digit number. That would be the new IP address you should try to connect to in Terraria.

Comment: Make sure you ignore the address listed as "*Default Gateway*", which is usually `192.168.1.1`. That's the address of your router, not your server.

Comment: @Nolonar My laptop has indeed gotten a new ip address but my sister's one is still the same old one and the LAN still does not work..

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding between us. You mentioned playing via LAN (Local Area Network), but is the server in your home (LAN), or somewhere on the internet (WAN, Wide Area Network)?

Comment: @Nolonar We use our at home WiFi to connect to each other we do it by starting up a "server" with the TerrariaServer.exe Application then both of us connect to it by clicking the "Multiplayer" option then "Join" and then typing the Host's ip (usually my sister's ipv4 address), she can get in just fine but it's usually when i try to get it that things get problematic... we have tried having me host it but just like before i can get in fine but she can't..

Comment: I see. Does it work if you turn off the firewall? Sometimes the firewall tends to block things even if you allowed them. PS: remember to turn the firewall back on when you're done.

Comment: @Nolonar We both made an inbound rule that allows Terraria through the firewall and we also unblocked Terraria from our Antivruses